# JQuery unable to get value from dynamically added Inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script here that I intend to run:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var sd = $("#StartDate").val();
        var ed = $("#EndDate").val();
        $("#userReportGenerate").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(sd);
            console.log(ed);
            $("<input/>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("id", "uStartDate").attr("name", "StartDate").attr("value", sd).appendTo("userReportForm");
            $("<input/>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("id","uEndDate").attr("name", "EndDate").attr("value", ed).appendTo("userReportForm");
            console.log($("#uStartDate").val());
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, when I click on the button, I get no value for the uStartDate ID. It just appears as blank on my console.

Is it possible to get the value from this input?

I intend to pass the StartDate and EndDate alongside my form when I submit it.

Comment: Ids have to be unique

Comment: You can pass an object to `.attr()`: `.attr({ type: "hidden", id: "uStartDate", name: ... })`

Comment: `.appendTo("userReportForm")` - The selector is wrong. Fix it and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var sd = $("#StartDate").val();
    var ed = $("#EndDate").val();
    $("#userReportGenerate").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let uStartDate='<input type="hidden" id="uStartDate" name="StartDate" value="'+sd+'">';
        $('#userReportForm').append(uStartDate); 
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: What did you change? And why?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.